# Can't read objects from a file

Tags: c++, file, object, header-files

So, to implement the file I/O, i made the following code. i also made a header file cuz i keep using it again and again. i am new to making header files, and including them so pls point out the mistakes and how to rectify them.

this is my header file

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H


class student
{
    public:
        void getstud();
        void putstud();
        int retroll();
        char* retname();
        int retclass();
        student();
        virtual ~student();
        student(const student& other);
    protected:
    private:
        int roll;
        char name[35];
        int Class;
};

#endif // STUDENT_H
```

and this is the corresponding cpp file

```
#include "student.h"


using namespace std;
void student::getstud()
{
    cout<<"\nenter the roll number : "; cin>>roll;
    cin.clear(); cin.ignore(1);
    cout<<"\nenter the name        : "; cin.getline(name, 35);
    cout<<"\nenter the class       : "; cin>>Class;
}

void student::putstud()
{
    cout<<"\nroll number : "<<roll;
    cout<<"\nname        : "<<name;
    cout<<"\nClass       : "<<Class;
}

int student::retroll() {return roll;}

char* student::retname() {return name;}

int student::retclass() {return Class;}

student::student()
{
    //ctor
}

student::~student()
{
    //dtor
}

student::student(const student& other)
{
    //copy ctor
}
```

and this is the program :

```
# include <fstream>
# include <conio.h>
# include "student.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    student s, s2;
    fstream file;

    file.open("recs.dat", ios::binary);
    cout<<"enter the details of a student :\n";
    s.getstud();
    file.write((char *)&s, sizeof(s));
    file.seekg(0); file.clear();
    file.read((char *)&s2, sizeof(s2));
    s2.putstud();
    s.putstud();
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

the output comes something like

```
enter the details of the student :
enter roll number : 23
enter name        : danny
enter Class       : 12

roll number  : (some number)
name         :
class        : 8
roll number  : 23
name         : danny
class        : 12
```

what could go wrong? pls help.

Comment: `file.open("recs.dat", ios::binary);`  -- Stop this.  You cannot store or retrieve non-POD objects this way.  The entire approach of your code is wrong.  You should be `serializing` the data, not copying raw bytes of a class instance (which contains a virtual function).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write and read object of class into and from binary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046829/write-and-read-object-of-class-into-and-from-binary-file)

Comment: Let's run the [POD test](http://ideone.com/tahGCL) on your `student` class, shall we?  Yep, cannot be saved using your techniques.  Note that the other `struct` I tested **is** a POD type.  Your technique will only work correctly for POD types, and not just that, POD types that do not contain pointers.